# Ill-posed problem: Local volatility calibration. Regularization vs Smoothing

Tags: calibration, local-volatility, interpolation, parabolic-pde

I have asked my question on Mathematics site of Stack Exchange but maybe I will get the answer rather here.

I am working on inverse problem - calibration of local volatility (financial application). This inverse problem is ill-posed. The optimization algorithm takes a $ \sigma $ surface as input and solves a PDE to calculate the cost function for each input. After inputs are evolved following genetic algorithm rules.
There are several authors proposing next approaches to regularize the input surface:

1. Regularization by means of Tikhonov
2. Smoothing using B-splines
3. Regularization using multiscale approach

Some authors use on of the first two approaches.
However, the author of my article uses both of them([Main Article](http://www.proba.jussieu.fr/pageperso/ramacont/papers/evolution.pdf)). For example the smoothness norm is introduced as:

$ \|\sigma\|^2 = \sum_{i}^{T} \int_{-A}^{A} dx \int_{0}^{T}|\frac{d\sigma}{dT}|^2 + |\frac{d^2\sigma}{dx^2}|^2 dx$

or in matrix form:

$ \|\sigma\|^2 = \theta A \theta^{T} $

where

$ \theta $ is a matrix of control points in B-Spline representation and

$ \sigma(T_{i},\cdot) = \sum_{m=1}^{M} \theta(i,m)\phi_{m}(\cdot) $

$ \sigma(t,x) = \frac{T_{i+1}-t}{T_{i+1}-T_{i}}\sigma(T_{i},x)+\frac{t-T_{i}}{T_{i+1}-T_{i}}\sigma(T_{i+1},x) $

are spline and linear interpolations by $x$ and $T$ axis respectively.
After the authors use Cholesky decomposition to obtain matrix $B$ such that $ A = BB^{T} $. 
Finally they use genetic optimization algorithm to perform random changes of control points: $ \theta_{new} = \theta + B\epsilon_{i} $.

The PDE is solved again with new candidate solutions $ \theta_{new} $ until the stopping criteria is not achieved.

Basically I do not understand the difference between regularization and smoothing.

What I do understand:

- B-Splines allow us to obtain a smooth representation of a function of interest
- Regularization is putting some convenient constraint on the function to be optimized (including the constraint of smoothness).

Isn't it enough to introduce a spline representation of the surface? (won't it be already smooth - as I understand it will).

Why do not we apply the random change directly on $ \theta $? kind of $\theta_{new} = \theta+\epsilon_{i}$

The role of smoothness norm knowing that B-Spline function is apriori smooth is not clear for me.
Thanks!

Comment: Usually practitioners calibrate the **implied** volatility surface and then compute on the fly the **local** volatility using Dupire's formula. I am curious as to why you want to calibrate the local volatility surface directly.

Comment: Apologies if I'm misinterpreting your question or saying something obvious. Something that's quite standard in polynomial curve fitting is to fit a higher order polynomial (to have a more flexible functional form) but then use regularization to penalize overfitting and push the fitted polynomial curve smoother in some aesthetic sense (rather than a precise mathematical, continuous $k$th derivative sense).

Comment: @MatthewGunn So basically B-spline smoothing is already a kind of regularization? I mean the term smoothing is equivalent to regularization? Because as you said, the B-Spline by definition does not pass by all control points, preventing the overfitting, but creates a smooth curve in aesthetic sense

Comment: @AntoineConze Rama Cont in his article claims why Dupire formula is unstable: Dupire (1994) presents a formula for reconstructing local volatility functions from a continuum of call option prices; however, this formula involves taking derivatives from discrete data and is numerically
unstable. A discretized version of the Dupire formula is the implied tree method of Derman et al (1996), which is prone to similar instabilities leading to “negative probabilities”

Comment: The standard approach is to build a smooth **implied** volatility surface from option prices and then to apply the Dupire formula to the implied volatility surface. If you calibrate directly a local volatility surface you will have a hard time computing vegas.